# Python find same elemts in an optional amount of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I'm looking for a way to find an element that exists in an optional amount of lists.

Currently I'm able to find it in two lists:

```py
def Mengen(liste1, liste2):
    print(liste2)
    A = set(liste1)
    B = set(liste2)
    
    if (A & B):
        return(A & B)
```

I now would like to expand that for multiple lists. I already tried to use pointers but I weren't able to make this work.
Has anyone a good way to solve that problem?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Edit:

The function is called like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [4,5,6,7]
c = [4,8,9,20]
d = [4,567,756,456,423]

Mengen(a,b)
```

And the output should be just a 4 or [4]

Comment: Does it need to be in *all* the `list`s, or some specific number of them? Give some example inputs and expected outputs so we have a better idea of the intent.

Comment: Oh yeah, I edited the question to hopefully make the input more clear. In the example I just called the first two lists but I'd like to change the amount of lists that I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want "what's in every input", this can be done easily with [`set`'s `intersection` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) (which takes varargs, and does not require them to be `set`s themselves, so you can pass *all* of your arguments save the first to it), and it does it all in one efficient operation:

```
def common_entries(iterable, *rest):
    return list(set(iterable).intersection(*rest))
```

This improves on [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66564055/364696) in a few ways (I originally began this as a comment suggesting improvements, but it got involved enough that I decided to separate it):

1. I removed a multiple unnecessary list comprehensions (the inner listcomp is completely unnecessary; `[i for i in args]` needlessly makes a `list` from the `tuple` received when you could just use `args` directly)
2. It avoids a ton of temporary sets you don't strictly need (`set.intersection`'s arguments can be any iterable; you don't need to convert them)
3. Since one input is mandatory (the original code would explode in a more confusing way if you passed no arguments), you can accept it separately, making the code allowed by #2 neater

For the simple test input of:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [4,5,6,7]
c = [4,8,9,20]
d = [4,567,756,456,423]
```

my `common_entries(a, b, c, d)` takes roughly half the time to run as the other answer's `findDuplicates(a, b, c, d)`, and reduces the number of explicit temporaries from `n + 2` to zero (internally, `set.intersection` does make temporary `set`s to represent progressive `intersection` results, but those can't be avoided in any reasonable way).

Answer (score 0):

```
def findDuplicated(*args):
    return list(set.intersection(*[set(j) for j in [i for i in args]]))

findDuplicated([1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [4,8,9,20], [4,567,756,456,423])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Set1 = set(input().split())
Set2 = set(input().split())
Set3 = set(input().split())
Set4 = set(input().split())
Set5 = Set1.intersection(Set2)
Set6 = Set3.intersection(Set4)

print(Set5.intersection(Set6))
```

The input should be in the format of this:

```
1 2 3 4
4 5 6 7
4 9 10
4 567 572
```

It has to be separated by the space, but this should work.